# posting an image to a php script that does expect it

Tags: php, post, tmp

if an image is posted to a php script but the php script isn't expecting an image to be posted to it, what happens to the posted image? does it still go into the /tmp folder on the server?

example:

```
<form action="myscript.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

my script:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: It goes to tmp and waiting for to be read

Comment: yes php will upload it in upload_tmp_dir defined in php.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it still gets into the /tmp directory, but it gets deleted when the script finishes executing.

Comment: thanks, but how can i stop this? as someone is trying to upload a malicious image which then ends up in my /tmp and the anti virus then catches it and sets the file permissions to zero

Comment: Maybe configure your antivirus to delete it instead of changing its permissions?

Comment: if you don't want any upload on server then you can set `file_uploads = Off` from php.ini file

Comment: thanks, i still need file uploads in the admin area can i set this at run time?

Comment: The file will be uploaded before the execution of the script and the antivirus will set its permissions to zero before you get to do anything within the script.

Answer (score 0):

whatever you posted through form will go to the server

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

it will be uploaded to `upload_tmp_dir` defined in `php.ini` file.

it will deleted once your php file finish execution.